# From an Interface how do I return a generic/dynamic type from a function

Tags: vb.net, generics

I would like to create in an interface a function that would look something along these lines;

```
Function GetRecords AS Ilist(of T)
```

When the interface is being implemented I would envisage the 'T' being substituted for example by User or Customer Or Supplier  etc.  The compiler obviously doesn't like T on its own pointing out that it's not defined. I understand that but it must surely be possible to define something generic.  I have tried using Type but that leads to awkward type conversions. Using Object appears to be more successful, but I can't find a definitive best practice or example of this.

Whilst I have used IList(of T) as an example it could just as easily be an IEnumerable(of T) or ICollection(of T).  Can I actually do this in an interface?  This is to be done in vb.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a generic interface the same way as you do when you create a generic class.

```
Public Interface IRecords(Of T)

    Function GetRecords() As IList(Of T)

End Interface
```

Usage:

```
Public Class Foo
    Implements IRecords(Of Foo)

    Public Function GetRecords() As IList(Of Foo) Implements IRecords(Of Foo).GetRecords
        'Return ...
    End Function

End Class
```

---

Another option is to create a generic function inside a "normal" interface:

```
Public Interface IRecords
    Function GetRecords(Of T)() As IList(Of T)
End Interface
```

Usage:

```
Public Class Foo
    Implements IRecords

    Public Function GetRecords(Of T)() As IList(Of T) Implements IRecords.GetRecords
        'Return ...
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for the two very clear examples, just what I needed.